# ResultSet.getBlob() very slow on ojdbc8

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, blob

I want to upgrade the jdbc-driver of my project.
Currently i´m using ojdbc5.jar.
I want to upgrade to ojdbc8.jar.

I've noticed that reading the blobs is now much slower.

```
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
        try (final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from BLOB_TABLE")) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    final Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("MYBLOB");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The table contains 10.000 entries.
It takes ~0.1 seconds with the ojdbc5 driver.
And it takes ~5-6 seconds with the ojdbc8 driver.

Im using Oracle Database XE 11.2 and 12.2 and Java 8.
Any solutions?

Comment: You could try contacting Oracle support for advice / help.

Comment: What happens to the performance if you actually fetch data from the blob? Just doing `getBlob` and then not using the blob is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The newer driver does more than just fetching the lob locator, it also prefetches data from the LOB. So it may be more expensive to call `resultSet.getBlob(columnName)` but calling `blob.getBytes()` will be faster. Overall the performance should be better with the newer driver.